# Thread pool thread & listening for event

Tags: c#

I have a threadpool thread which has subscribed for an event, and the event handler gets fired on another thread. My question is-when will the thread pool thread be returned back to the pool or is it going to linger around as long as the event subscription is active?

For ex:

```
public class RunTasks
    {
        private readonly MyTask _myTask;

        public RunTasks(MyTask myTask)
        {
            _myTask = myTask;
        }

        public void Execute()
         {
             ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((ignore) => _myTask.Execute());
         }
    }

    public class MyTask
    {
        private readonly IThridPartyApi _dependency;

        public MyTask(IThridPartyApi dependency)
        {
            _dependency = dependency;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _dependency.UpdateEvent -= Handler;
            _dependency.UpdateEvent += Handler;
        }

        private void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //raised on another thread as it's coming from a thrid party library.
        }
    }

    public interface IThridPartyApi
    {
        event EventHandler<EventArgs> UpdateEvent;
    }
```

In the above example let us say RunTasks.Execute method gets called multiple times (range of 100) and the event handler gets fired for 50 of them and was delayed for the next 50 - how many active threads will be listening for the event subscription? I have this scenario in my application, so is trying to make sure that I'm not creating a monster out of this implementation. Please can you help me with an answer and a reason? Also if this is not a efficent implementation, how can I modify it(without using async as we are still not there)? Note that the Execute method is getting fired from UI button handler.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Why are you implementing your own tasks instead of using TPL? It solves such problems in a much simpler way. Besides, if you wanted event handlers to fire asynchronously (ie using `async`), you'd still need to use the TPL Tasks.

Comment: I dont use async as we are still not there. I can use TPL however-but how does that resolve this?

Comment: The way the code is right now, a ThreadPool thread just sets up a handler and is released. The handler gets executed by the thir-party's thread. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: The question is-is it released?

Comment: Yes, as soon as Execute returns

Answer (score 0):

The way the code looks right now, a ThreadPool thread is used simply to reset an event handler, then it's released back to the pool. The event handler will run in the thread of whoever raises the UpdateEvent event, ie the third-party API's thread(s).

To avoid this, you can convert the event to a Task using a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is described in [TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the section `Exposing Complex EAP operations as Tasks`. This way, the event handler will run asynchronously in a ThreadPool thread, and the third-party's thread won't be blocked waiting for it.

In your case, you could create a function like the following to return a task that retur:

```
public static Task<object> OnUpdateAsync(this IThridPartyApi dependency)
{
    var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    EventHandler handler=null;
    handler=(obj,args)=>
    {
        dependency.UpdateEvent-=handler;
        //extract the response here
        tcs.SetResult(response);
    }
    dependency.UpdateEvent+=handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can change the return type from `object` to whatever you expect to receive from the third-party API.